# Why does Cloud build not persist my files after RUN commands

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

We have a Cloud Build CI pipeline setup to pull our base Wordpress image and build it into a docker image for deployment. When I run the build using our Dockerfile locally everything works as expected, but on Cloud Build any files created during the build do not show up in the final image.

Even running an `ls` mid build shows the files are there but once completed they're gone.

```
FROM us-docker.pkg.dev/ProjectImageWithApacheAndSQL

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y

# From official Docker image doc - Static image / updates-via-redeploy
# Disable override in the /var/www/html/ directory
RUN set -eux; \
    find /etc/apache2 -name '*.conf' -type f -exec sed -ri -e "s!/var/www/html!$PWD!g" -e "s!Directory /var/www/!Directory $PWD!g" '{}' +;

# SETUP Node and NPM
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

COPY src /var/www/html/

# Override wp-config.php 
COPY Build/wp-config.php /var/www/html/wp-config.php

# Install Gulp globally
RUN npm install -g gulp

RUN cd /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/treadmillv3 && \
npm i && gulp build


RUN cd /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/treadmillv3 && \ 
echo ls -lta > buildLog.txt


CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Comment: Review your question format and do you have issue with Docker or Cloud Build, it's not clear enough

Comment: Thanks to @kangasta for the edit. The issue is with cloud build specifically. The above Docker file runs fine locally using a normal docker build command,